# Text Selection Scroll not working in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, scroll

I have an issue in content scrolling in IE. I have a div which set overflow auto. It contains some text content. When I try to click and drag on content, normally it scroll and select up to bottom of the content; Chrome and FF working fine. but in IE it select only visible area, not scroll and select bottom content. If use scroll button in mouse it will work.

```
<div class="dvContainer">
    (long text here)
</div>

.dvContainer{
    height:200px;
    width:500px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yfea2mu5/2/

How can solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Add code and some minor formatting changes.

Comment: What is the IE version? I tested IE version 11 on localhost and it works well

Comment: did you ever find a fix for this is issue @Musthaan